# Split shipping cost in cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce, woothemes

I have Shipping costs based on the number of categories in cart. Base shipping is 250 and if the number of categories is more than 1 for every category is charged extra 50. At the moment everything is shown together in a cart, I would like to be extra cost visible with a label and new row. [image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might need to [modify the WooCommerce checkout template](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) in the theme that you are using.